# how can I take only file name and size from the du -sh command result

Tags: disk-usage

Here is my result: these are my postgresql backup files, but I want to keep only the size and filenames for log file. I don't want to display directory path. Is there a simple solution?

This is my command:

```
du  -sh /storage/sqlBackup/* | sort -n


2.3G    /storage/sqlBackup/SqlBackup20160126000501
4.0K    /storage/sqlBackup/000000010000000E000000F8.00000028.backup
16M     /storage/sqlBackup/000000010000000E000000F8
16M     /storage/sqlBackup/000000010000000E000000F9
16M     /storage/sqlBackup/000000010000000E000000FA

I want it like this:
2.3G    SqlBackup20160126000501
4.0K    000000010000000E000000F8.00000028.backup
16M     000000010000000E000000F8
16M     000000010000000E000000F9
16M     000000010000000E000000FA
```

Comment: This question has probably been answered but , this will get you going for now:  `awk -F/ '{print $1"\t"$NF}'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you better results:

```
(cd /storage/sqlBackup; du -sh * | sort -h)
```

(note the `-h` parameter to `sort`).

Comment: this worked fine too,but I wanted to order by desc createdate thats why I put sort -n

Comment: `sort -n` just sorts numerically, in this case on the size since that's what's in `du`'s output, not by creation date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` also.

I could say you can do the following

```
$ du  -sh /storage/sqlBackup/* | sed 's|/storage/sqlBackup/||g' | sort -h
```